# Rendering hidden custom elements in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

Is it possible to create a custom div element (expand-contract fashion) in between rows of ag-grid, for each row of the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, but I think you are looking for either one of the below.

1. [Master / Detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/).
2. [Tree Data](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/)
3. [Row Grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/)

Comment: I looked into these features before, but the drop-downs provided again contains a grid. What I need is a custom DOM element in the Master/detail feature instead of the grid itself.Is it possible?

Comment: You can update the template yourself - check the example provided in the same page
1: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#example-custom-detail-with-grid, 2: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#example-custom-detail-cell-renderer-with-a-form